# Line integral ( Stokes' Theorem)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\gamma$ : intesection of $z=x^{2}-y^{2}$ with $3x^{2}+4y^{2}=1$
Am supposed to calculate the line integral over the intersection.

$\int \bar{F}dr = \int \int Curl\bar{F}dS $

CurlF =$ (7y^{6},5z^{4},3x^{2})$

How to parametrize the surface here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A nice parameterization could include $x = \frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}\cos{\theta}$ and $y = \frac{r}{2}\sin{\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to parametrize that portion of the surface $z=x^2-y^2$ lying "over" the elliptical region $3x^2+4y^2\le 1$ in the $xy$-plane. This seems to turn into a rather yucky double integral, although if you use symmetry considerations it won't be too bad. Here's what the picture looks like:

[image: Curve on saddle]